# Voltage in traveler wires 3 way switch

Tags: switch, light

If I measure the voltage between the two traveler wires in my 3 way switch, I see 8 to 12 volts.

Is it normal to have that much voltage on travelers?

Answer (score 1):

The whole deal with travelers is that one is hot, and one is not.

[image]

If the lamp is on, then one traveler is disconnected at both ends and will read **nothin'** to the other traveler - no meaningful voltage and no conductance.

Any readings other than that are a meter error, or a wiring fault.

If the lamp is off, then the hot traveler is connected to hot, and the "not" traveler is connected to the lamp's switched-hot wire.  The conductance of the lamp itself will pull it to neutral voltage, causing the wires to read "line voltage" between them.

Comment: "Any readings other than that are a meter error, or a wiring fault."
Only for direct current.
In case of alternating current supplies, the parallel lines/travellers are a sort of capacitor that can transport some tiny amount of current. And there are more capacities between each of that traveller to neutral (lines  nearby) and/or ground (water tubes, metal conduit, rebars in concrete etc.).
For non-zero frequencies, there will be always some  current flowing through those unavoidable capacitors (voltage divider), and the sensitive DMM will show some non-zero- values.

Comment: @xeeka you are talking about phantom voltage, which is a vexation of troubleshooting AC power.  It can only be detected by meters which are too sensitive for practical use in AC mains, such as cheapie DVMs.  That impedance needs to be lowered to get a meaningful reading.

Answer (score 0):

If lights is on, one wire is under voltage, another loose, not connected to anything. So you measurement is irrelevant, could be any value, depends on your voltmeter input resistance. If lights off, should be full voltage, one wire is phase, another connected to neutral trough load.

Comment: I get that you would change from off to on, but 8 volts wouldn't make sense. One terminal would always have 120 and the other wouldn't.

Comment: @JasonMichaels What voltage you can measure between 120V and nothing? Second terminal of voltmeter on air. Some induced current.

Comment: induced voltage is not an old wives tale, esp, with wires in cables that run some distance with each other.   I recently helped a master electrician doing some grunt work at our church's heating system.  I kept getting zapped even though the circuits were def. turned off.  I measured it at about 160-170 volts.  I put an old style incandescent bulb in the circuit and the reading dropped to zero. I wore rubber gloves for the rest of the grunt work. DMMs are so sensitive that without any sort of load, they can give all sorts of readings.

Comment: @georgeanderson you kept getting zapped not because of induced current, but because the bed disconnect, which still had some finite resistance. Current affect the human body, not voltage. When you connect incandescent bulb, it worked like voltage divider, voltage reduced because the bulb resistance much lower then disconnect.

Comment: @user263983  I get that.  Current kills, not voltage.    But no, it was induced current, not a bad disconnect. The wires were in conduit for a long ways and it was clearly induced current.

Comment: @georgeanderson. Long run, the isolation not perfect. So, leakage was not in disconnect but through isolation in cable.